What's the official German translation for Revel's End?
I am currently reading through Rime of the Frostmaiden, a book only released in English. I have also acquired the free adventure Prisoner 13 from D&D Beyond, also in English. Both of these talk about a prison called Revel's End located at the northern shore of Icewind Dale. Me and my players are however playing in German. Reading in English is not a problem for me, I would however like to translate this name to German for all of us, were we to play one of these adventures.
It is quite a complicated name for a non-native speaker. Therefore I am looking for any official translation for the name of this prison.
If I understand correctly Revel's End is a relatively new addition to the lore of the Forgotten Realms and has only appeared in three official products, that I know of:

Icewind Dale - Rime of the Frostmaiden (available only in English)
The D&D Movie Honor Among Thieves (available in English and German)
Keys from the Golden Vault (available in English and German)

I have re-watched the first couple of minutes of the D&D movie which take place in Revel's End, but I was unable to find any mention of the prison's name in there and I do not own Keys of the Golden Vault in any language. Online I could find translations for many places in Icewind Dale, such as the Three Lakes or the Ten Towns, but not Revel's End. There is also this translator on a German site, it sadly doesn't include Revel's End either.
I even found this German description of Keys of the Golden Vault on D&D Beyond that mentions the prison as "Revel's End", i.e. untranslated. Which is frankly hard to believe for me. Is there really no German name for it?

Schlussmitlustig
The German Translation for Revel's End is "Schlussmitlustig". I found it looking through German review videos of Keys of the Golden Vault, it can be see on top of the map here.
The name is a portmanteau of the phrase "Schluss mit lustig!" which translates to "The Party is over!" or literally "It's the end of (being) funny!". In that regard it is a far more humorous name, than the gloomy "Revel's End", so one might have to adjust their game's tone a bit, if they plan to use the translated name.
This means the untranslated version on D&D Beyond is actually a mistake, as the name is in fact translated inside the book. Perhaps it was released before the book was fully translated?

A revel is a party or a celebration.  Lustig comes across into English in different ways depending on the context.   (I remember this song from my youth:
Lustig, lustig, tra la la la la!
Bald ist Nikolausabend da,
~
Jolly, jolly, tra la la la la!
Saint Nicholas Eve will soon be here!
Saint Nicholas Eve will soon be here!)
~ Your German term might be "end of joy" or "end of Jolliness" rather than "the end of the party" ~ a "revel" is 3.  boisterous festivity; merrymaking; revelry-an occasion of merrymaking or boisterous festivity; celebration
But I think you are close enough.

And I think that "It's the end of being fun" or "the end of having fun" is what you were aiming for.  Well done!

@KorvinStarmast Are you saying the German name is not as humorous as it seems to me and can actually be understood in a serious tone aswell?

@KorvinStarmast I got my translation from https://www.dict.cc/?s=Schluss+mit+lustig

I think you nailed it with "the party is over" because that is literally what "revel's end" means: the end of the party.  Well played, in either case!
